# C# Obtener el ValueMember de los items tildados en un checkedListbox

Tags: c#

Tengo una base de datos que guarda distritos tipos de `tickets` con su respectivo estado. Ese estado puede variar dependiendo el tipo de `ticket`.

Yo estoy haciendo una aplicación de `Windows Form` donde quiero sacar la información de la cantidad de `tickets` por estado. Esto lo he podido hacer sin problema.

Estoy trabado en lo siguiente, agregué un `checkedlistbox` para poder sacar la información de mas de un estado. Tengo una `DataTable` donde obtiene y guarda el `idestado` y el nombre del estado al momento de seleccionar el tipo de `ticket`, y de ahí se obtienen los distintos estados para un `combobox` de estados **(seleccionar de a un estado)** y también donde se obtienen los estados para el `checkedlistbox`:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Conexion cnx = new Conexion();
    string idTipoTicket = comboBoxTipoticket.SelectedValue.ToString();

    estadosTickets = cnx.LlenarDataTableWhere("idestado,nombre", "serviciotecnicoestados", "idestado in (select idestado from serviciotecnico_tiposdetickets_estados where idtipoticket=" + idTipoTicket + ");");
    comboBoxEstados.ValueMember = "idestado";
    comboBoxEstados.DisplayMember = "nombre";
    comboBoxEstados.DataSource = estadosTickets;

    checkedListBoxEstados.DataSource = estadosTickets;
    checkedListBoxEstados.DisplayMember = "nombre";
    checkedListBoxEstados.ValueMember = "idestado";

}
```

Necesito obtener el `idestado` de los `items` marcados en el `checkedlistbox` y asignarlos a un `string`, pero no lo estoy pudiendo lograr.

Sé que así puedo recorrer los distintos `items` y chequear si están marcados, pero no se como obtener el correspondiente `ValueMember` de ese `item`, para poder asignarlo e ir concatenandolo al `string` "**estados**".

```
string estados = "";
int x;

for(x=0;x<checkedListBoxEstados.Items.Count;x++)
{

}
```

Espero haber sido lo mas claro posible.
Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes recorrer en un ciclo "foreach" todos los items en "checked" de la siguiente forma:

```
         string estados = "";
         foreach (var item in checkedListBoxEstados.CheckedItems)
         {
             DataRowView dataRowView = item as DataRowView; //Suponiendo que estás utilizando un DataTable haces un cast pues item es de tipo object
             string id = Convert.ToString(dataRowView["idestado"]);
             estados+= id; 
         }
```

Espero te sea de utilidad. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Puede iterar la seleccion usando

```
List<string> listaSeleccion = new List<string>();

foreach(var item in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
{
    listaSeleccion.Add((item as ListItem).Value);
}
 string result = string.Join(", ", listaSeleccion);
```

como es una seleccion de varios elementos debes agregarlos a una lista y de esta unirlos para poner asignarlos al string

[Cómo: Determinar los elementos activados en el control CheckedListBox de formularios Windows Forms](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-determine-checked-items-in-the-windows-forms-checkedlistbox-control)